# Whats the easiest way to implement my google calendar to my jquery mobile website?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-calendar-api

I ve looked on the web on how to import my google calendar to my jquery mobile website. Most of them are custom made solutions , or ready made widjets for jquery mobile , that need to get feeded with data that i should parse from my google calendar.

I am really wondering , is there an easier way to do so? I thought that i could just add a few lines of code and the google calendar would be automatically imported in my jquery mobile website. The API doesnt provide that , or completely missed my attention?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the embed code that Google provides?  It's in 'Calendar Settings'.  Just paste the code in your site, or load it via jQuery and there's your calendar.

Comment: Yes i just found the code , but it doesnt seem to fit well my device screen. I think is meant to be for desktop use and not mobile. Maybe a plugin for jquery mobile would be better , and feed it with my calendars events.

Comment: Go to 'customise the color, etc' settings, select agenda view and set the width to 320.  I have used it many times in mobile applications.

Comment: Pff it still looks very bad though... Its almost half of it showing.. I can see till the print button , i dont know why.